# Replacing value in a column in pandas dataframe from a column value in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`

```
s = {'id': [4735,46,2345,8768,807],'city': ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f']}
s1 = {'id': [4735],'city_in_mail': ['x']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(s)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(s1)
```

`df1` looks like

```
     id city
0  4735    a
1    46    b
2  2345    d
3  8768    e
4   807    f
```

and `df2` looks like:

```
     id city_in_mail
0  4735            x
```

I want to replace the value of column `city` in dataframe `df1` from the value of column `city_in_mail` from dataframe `df2` for the row where the `id` value is same.

So my df1 should become:

```
     id city
0  4735    x
1    46    b
2  2345    d
3  8768    e
4   807    f
```

How can do this with pandas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `combine_first` with `rename` to align column index:

```
df2.set_index('id')\
   .rename(columns={'city_in_mail':'city'})\
   .combine_first(df1.set_index('id'))\
   .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
       id city
0  4735.0    x
1    46.0    b
2  2345.0    d
3  8768.0    e
4   807.0    f
```

Note: You can reassign this back to df1 if you choose.

Comment: @pygo Thank you.

Comment: this solution is failing if the row with matching id in df1 is not the first row

Comment: Ah... yes, you could set index to ID. I assumed that ID was the index.  My bad.

Answer (score 3):

Use indexes to match and then [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
df1 = df1.set_index('id')
df2 = df2.set_index('id')
df1.loc[df1.index.isin(df2.index), :] = df2.city_in_mail
```

Or use [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

```
c = df1.city
c.update(df2.city_in_mail)
df1['city'] = c
```

All outputs

```
        city
id  
4735    x
46      b
2345    d
8768    e
807     f
```

Of course, feel free to do `df1.reset_index()` in the end to go back to previous structure.

Answer (score 3):

Using `merge` with `.loc`

```
s=df1.merge(df2,how='outer')
s.loc[s.city_in_mail.notnull(),'city']=s.city_in_mail
s
  city    id city_in_mail
0    x  4735            x
1    b    46          NaN
2    d  2345          NaN
3    e  8768          NaN
4    f   807          NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Also `.map` + `.fillna` (if  `'id'` is a unique key in `df2`)

```
df1['city'] = df1.id.map(df2.set_index('id').city_in_mail).fillna(df1.city)

print(df1)
#     id city
#0  4735    x
#1    46    b
#2  2345    d
#3  8768    e
#4   807    f
```